# Searching in json string representation of array in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have an index in Azure Cognitive Search where one of the fields, Slugs, is a json string representation of an array, ie. `"slugs": "[\"111-something\", \"222-something-else\"]"`. The API accessing the data should be able to return items matching a given single slug, so I need to write a query string that returns items where the slugs string contains the given slug. The closest I've gotten is `$filter=search.ismatch('"111-something-something"', 'slugs')`, but this will also return items where the list of slugs contains 111-something-something-else, so I need to include the double quotes around it to mimic an "eq" filter. I have tried `$filter=search.ismatch('"\"111-something-something\""', 'slugs')` but items with `"slugs": "[\"111-something-something-something\"]"`  are still returned. Does anybody know how to write such a query string?

Comment: Can you try something like: `$filter=slugs/any(slug: slug eq '111-something')`?

Comment: The thing is that Slugs is a string, so that won't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Aah...I see. For some reason I thought it is an array.